# Use tika with python, runtimeerror: unable to start tika server

Tags: python, parsing, apache-tika

I am trying to use the tika package to Parse files. Tika is successfully installed, `tika-server-1.18.jar` runned with Code in cmd `Java -jar tika-server-1.18.jar`

My code in the Jupyter is:

```
import tika 
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('')
```

However, I receive below error:

> 2018-07-25 10:20:13,325 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to see startup
> log message; retrying... 2018-07-25 10:20:18,329 [MainThread  ]
> [WARNI]  Failed to see startup log message; retrying... 2018-07-25
> 10:20:23,332 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to see startup log
> message; retrying... 2018-07-25 10:20:28,340 [MainThread  ] [ERROR]
> Tika startup log message not received after 3 tries. 2018-07-25
> 10:20:28,340 [MainThread  ] [ERROR]  Failed to receive startup
> confirmation from startServer.
>
> RuntimeError: Unable to start Tika Server.

Comment: Any update to this question? I get the same error message.

Comment: I gave up using TIKA Server, instead, I used TikaApp to solve the problem. "tika_client = TikaApp(file_jar = ''(where i have stored the tika app). It works. For parser I haven't found a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: using TikaApp, `tika_client.extract_all_content(path_to_file)` returns an empty string

Comment: This answer has solved my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36628583/5403632

Answer (score 16):

According to [Apache Tika's site](https://tika.apache.org/), all new versions of the tika-server.jar will require Java 8.

> 24 April 2018: Apache Tika Release
>   Apache Tika 1.18 has been released! This release includes bug fixes (e.g. extraction from grouped shapes in PPT), security fixes and upgrades to dependencies. PLEASE NOTE: The next versions will require Java 8. Please see the CHANGES.txt file for the full list of changes in the release and have a look at the download page for more information on how to obtain Apache Tika 1.18.

Current outdated docs for tika Python library claim that Java 7 is needed, but now Java 8 must be installed. This is because the current version of tika-server.jar is automatically downloaded at runtime if not found in your temp file.

After installing Java 8, my basic test code launched the server and worked without error.

Comment: It's not necessary to install java while working with Apachetika.

Comment: I'm stuck in the same issue, I've posted a question too, could you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66445198/8340027). Seems like tika server is not starting, it returns Not Found 404.

Answer (score 10):

After you import Tika you need to initialize the Java Server

```
import tika
tika.initVM()
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('') //file name should be here
```

Comment: I tried the same way, I initialized it after import. It returns Not Founds 404. Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66445198/8340027).

Answer (score 3):

Download Java. If you already have a version of Java installed, try updating it to the latest version. The version that works for me is 1.18.

Answer (score 1):

You have not passed an argument (specified a file) in your line:

> parsed = parser.from_file('')

Give it a file to chew on e.g.,

```
parsed = parser.from_file('myfile.txt')
```

The server didn't start & presumably this no log warning gets triggered - see line 644 in the source at [the Github](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python/blob/master/tika/tika.py)

then another error message tells you it ain't going to play...

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. Tried all steps mentioned here, nothing helped.
How I solved it:

1. checked the log file of tika and tika-server.
   For windows, you can find it inside `C:/Users/your_user_name/AppData/Local/Temp/`
2. Found that tika-server log had mentioned port already in use error.

check below log snippet -

```
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:9998/
WARNING: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@localhost:9998: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:417)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:49)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory.addListener(JAXRSBindingFactory.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:206)
        at org.apache.tika.server.TikaServerCli.main(TikaServerCli.java:213)
```

3. This clearly indicated that another process is already running in same port. So I just needed to kill java process running on `port 9998` (which I assumed might have been defunct)
4. Once I killed the process in task manager, I tried rerunning the python script, it worked correctly.
5. To cross check you can also run the tika-server.jar file present in same path - `C:/Users/your_user_name/AppData/Local/Temp/` using below command and check if it fails or runs correctly: `java -jar tika-server.jar`

Hope this will be helpful to someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and solved using steps below:

1. Check my tika server log file (usually its located at C:/Users/your_user_name/AppData/Local/Temp/)

   **2023-04-02 08:06:47,277 [Thread-1 (pr] [ERROR]  Unable to run java; is it installed?
   2023-04-02 08:06:47,278 [Thread-1 (pr] [ERROR]  Failed to receive startup confirmation from startServer.**
2. It is suspected Java is not being installed. So check if Java is being installed using

   **java -version**
3. If it's not installed, you may download it here: https://www.java.com/en/download/.
4. If still error, try to start Tika server manually using:

   **java -jar tika-server.jar**

- Remember run it at where your jar file is located. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Ubuntu 20.01 (and 18.04) like me, the solution is to Install Oracle JDK 17. Do the following:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java17-installer
```

Type `java -version` on the terminal. You should see the following print-out:

```sh
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS`
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)`
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

`tika` should then be able to extract text from your pdf in `python`.

```py
parser.from_file(<your pdf file>)
```